# How to :edit executable from path?

Tags: command-line, normal-mode, edit, execute

Environment: Linux

*I apologize in advance if this question already exists somewhere and has a proper answer.
It is just so difficult for me to search because the keywords are all so generic.*

Put simply, I want to know a way to do what one might expect this to do:

`:edit !which command`

This gives the following error:

`E172: Only one file name allowed`

because the parameters to edit are not being evaluated.

I have tried various incantations with execute, eval, and even norm but I can't make the magic work.

Comment: Use backticks, see [:h backtick-expansion](https://vimhelp.org/editing.txt.html#backtick-expansion)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I *think* this is what you want to do. I just tested it and it worked for me.

```
:edit `which command`
```

Wrap the argument to `:edit` in backticks rather than preceding it with a "!".

Comment: Thanks but that is actually giving me this different error:

```
:e \`which my_script.py`

E79: Cannot expand wildcards

"`which my_script.py`" [New File]

```
(Sorry, can't figure out how to do block of code in comments)

Comment: please update your answer and remove the backslash and it will be correct:
`:edit \`which command\``
You have to type:
<backtick>:edit <backslash><backtick>which command<backslash><backtick><backtick> in order for it to display in the answer correctly.

Comment: @JoshThies Oh, dear. I hadn't meant to type that backslash. I'm sorry.